# Create an array in Page-based app on Xcode 7

Tags: ios

I am trying to do a "snapchat like menu". and I have no ideas of how I can replace the months with my own array of views in the page-based app (the original Xcode code).
I've tried lots of ways to change this into an array but none of my tries worked

This is the code given in the ModelController.m:

```
- (instancetype)init 
{
self = [super init];
if (self) {

    // Create the data model.
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    _pageData = [[dateFormatter monthSymbols] copy];
}
return self;
}
```

Any kind of help would be really nice!

Answer (score 0):

Greetings and welcome to iOS development!

In order to replace the month views with your own views, you will need to create your own new array that will serve as the pages. Then make _pageData pull from that new array instead of the months.

example:

```
NSArray *pagesArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
pagesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Page One", @"Page Two", @"Page Three", nil];
_pageData = [pagesArray copy];
```

Good luck, and godspeed.